# object reference not set to an instance error while login in asp.net application using google

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-social-plugins, google-signin, geojson

i am implementing google login in my website. Using asspsnippets.dll.

I am getting object reference not set to an instance error in this line on page load

```
string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
```

My complete code is here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace AdventureSports.Public
{
    public partial class google_login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleConnect.ClientId = "<My client Id>";
            GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "<My secret code>";
            GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
            {
                string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
                GoogleProfile profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleProfile>(json);
                lblId.Text = profile.Id;
                lblName.Text = profile.DisplayName;
                lblEmail.Text = profile.Emails.Find(email => email.Type == "account").Value;
                lblGender.Text = profile.Gender;
                lblType.Text = profile.ObjectType;
                ProfileImage.ImageUrl = profile.Image.Url;
                pnlProfile.Visible = true;
                btnLogin.Enabled = false;
            }

            if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
            }
        }

        protected void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleConnect.Authorize("profile", "email");
        }

        protected void Clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleConnect.Clear();
        }

        public class GoogleProfile
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public Image Image { get; set; }
            public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string ObjectType { get; set; }
        }

        public class Email
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Image
        {
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a querystring parameter with the name 'code'.
This error mostly occurs if querystring parameter has null value.Put the break point and check the value of your querystring parameter 'code'.Hope the value is not assigned properly to querystring parameter 'code'.

Comment: also check by putting Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString("code")); since you are assigning querystring parameter to a string value.

Comment: query string code has values and i have converted to string also. But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: you are assigning same name to both querystring parameter and string parameter. I'm not sure,but it may clash. change it and run after pressing ctrl+f5.

Comment: press ctrl+f5 while running in browser.

Comment: i changed string parameter name. but getting the same error again.. :(

Comment: please check whether the querystring parameter is clearing some where in your application.ie in page load of some other cs file.I got the same issue solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

dll only the problem. download new dll from below url and refer this sample code

[facebook login using asp.net](http://www.studyoverflow.org/2013/05/retrieve-facebook-user-profile-details.html)